# Loading local template into external template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, ionic-framework

Sorry about the title, not certain of a better subject line.

In my ionic project I have a popover window that I use alot but its repeated a lot through different pages.  Currently, every popover is uniquely defined in every controller/page view....which means I need to edit every instance of the popover in every page if I want to change one element of the page.

To clean things up, I want to move the embedded script/template to an external file that would be called like:

```
  $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/popover.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    focusFirstInput: false 
  }).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  });
```

Easy enough...however, some popovers require custom HTML & custom $scope variables.  Is it possible to define local `<script>` template code that can be passed into the external template?  Something like:

Main template:

```
<ion-view id="view">
  <ion-nav-title>
    ... 
  </ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content id="thisContent">

     <script id="popoverExtras.html" type="text/ng-template">
         <div id="customDiv1"> {{data1}} .. some content .. </div>
         <div id="customDiv2"> {{data2}} .. more content .. </div>
     </script>  
  </ion-content>
</ion-view">
```

External Template:

```
<ion-popover-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title" style="text-align:center;">{{popTitle}} </h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content drag-content=“false”>
     <div id="subject">{{popSubject}}</div>
     <div id="message">{{popMessage}}</div>

     <script id="popoverExtras.html" type="text/ng-template">
     </script>

  </ion-content>
</ion-popover-view>
```

And still load the entire external + local template into a single popover view with the standard load:

```
  $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/popover.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    focusFirstInput: false 
  }).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  });
```